# How to assign pre- and post-launch actions for applications?

Tags: linux, application-launch

Is there any way to automatically assign pre- and post-launch actions to applications in Linux?

Exaple scanario: When I launch Virtualbox, `vboxdrv` is loaded transparently; when I close Virtualbox, the module gets unloaded automatically.

Comment: For this particular scenario, why not just load vboxdrv permanently at boot?

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to wrap the application in a script

```
#
pre_action
application
post_action
```

Then invoke that script instead of invoking the application directly

Comment: Thanks, this is ok with additional signal handling. I am searcing for a more universal solution though.

Comment: A wrapper script is as universal as you can possibly get. You can perform *any* pre/post action with it, for *any* program in *any* system.